# scrolltop function not focusing the element correctly

Tags: jquery

I am using a function to focus on the content of the div, i used this function, but onclick the content not focusing properly. while i click on the third link it focus on the second, as well the fourth focusing 3rd content... it works buggy.. any idea?

my code is :

```
$(function(){
        $('#navi a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault(); 
            move($(this).attr("href")); 
        })

        function move(id){
            $('#content').animate({scrollTop:$(id).offset().top},'slow');
        }
    })
```

while i alert and get the offset().top, it show the wrong values on each time..
i am taking the id's from 'a''s href. thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML.  If you can, create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue you are having.

Answer (score 1):

Ok...so you want the #content to scroll to a child, but you're using the elements offset which is based on the window. Try this:

```
$('#content').animate({scrollTop:$(id).position().top},'slow');
```

Or maybe you want to scroll the window?

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(id).offset().top},'slow');
```

If none of those work for you, please post som html.

Comment: I am sorry, i implemented a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your href doesn't contain "#", try :

```
$('#content').animate({scrollTop:$("#"+ id).offset().top},'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, isn't it a height issue? Try this:

```
$('#content').animate({scrollTop:$(id).offset().top+$(id).height()},'slow');
```